# Randomly choosing from multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, random

I have 3 lists and want a way that Python chooses multiple options from all lists. How can I do this?

I've tried the code below, but it only gives me 1 option in total.

```
list_1 = [1,3,5]

list_2 = [2,4,6]

list_3 = [10]

random.choice([random.choice(list_1)] + [random.choice(list_2)] + 
              [random.choice(list_3)])
```

Comment: Were you expecting a result like `(1, 6, 10)`? (or perhaps `[1, 6, 10]`?) - in that case, you shouldn't pick randomly again from the previous results (that's what you're doing), but just combine the result in a list or tuple. Or is a result like `[6,1,3]` also OK? In that case, first combine the lists and then pick randomly from the result.

Comment: For the supplied input lists, what outputs should be possible, and what should their relative probabilities be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the random.sample function to retrieve multiple random values

syntax : random.sample(list,k) where k is the number of values to be sampled.

```
list_1 = [1,3,5]

list_2 = [2,4,6]

list_3 = [10]

random.sample(list_1+list_2+list_3,3)
```

[edit]

if you want one from each list,

```
final_list = random.sample(list_1,1)+random.sample(list_2,1)+random.sample(list_3,1)
```

this can be done using random.choice as below

```
final_list =[ random.choice(list_1),random.choice(list_2),random.choice(list_3)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work. And what if I wanted 1 option from list_1, 1 option from list_2 and 1 option from list_3?

Comment: edited.. if you find the answer appropriate, mark it as accepted answer, with the green checkmark on the left side. happy learning.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much venkata krishnan!

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but from what I think you are trying to ask:

To make a random choice from a few lists, you could try this:

```
list_1 = [1,3,5]

list_2 = [2,4,6]

list_3 = [10]

random.choice([random.choice(list_1), random.choice(list_2), random.choice(list_3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
list_1 = [1,3,5]
list_2 = [2,4,6]   
list_3 = [10]

[random.choice(list_1)+random.choice(list_2)+random.choice(list_3)]
```

this would give:

```
 [1,6,10]
```